# How close do waves have to be for their wave functions to cancel?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation

I was thinking about waves canceling today and started wondering about this. Is there an equation relating the lateral separation of two identical but out of phase waves to how much they are canceled? Is it related to the amplitude? If so would this just cause a dimming of the resultant beam if, say, two out of phase lasers were pointed in the same direction, while close to but not perfectly on top of one another? Lastly if your dealing with only two photons at a time is there still a dimming effect? It doesn't seem right to dim individual photons.

Comment: You can't dim a photon.  It's an indivisible unit of energy, and hence intensity.   Interference happens point-by-point in space.  Where the waves overlap, they can interfere.  Where they don't, they can't.

Comment: As garyp already pointed out, waves don't cancel. Linear superposition conserves energy, i.e. for every decrease in amplitude in one point, there has to be an increase somewhere else. Photons are local measurements on the quantum field of electromagnetic radiation. They only "exist" where we measure them and it doesn't make much sense to talk about photons when we don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a comment to your last question, but I will post it as an answer to add a link.

It is actually quite hard to create a single photon in real life. Moreover phase and number operators do not commute, so the last question doesn't make much sense.

One can check [this website](http://www.iqst.ca/quantech/research/fock.php) for very nice discussion on the topic